# Create a DLL from HEX Code

Tags: dll, hex, binary-data

I've got the hex code of a DLL (which was added as an assembly in my SQL DB).
Is there a way to use this hex code to rebuild my dll?

The DLL is a .net dll, written in VB.

Comment: I don't understand your question exactly, but why don't you just get the hex code out of the db, convert it to binary and save it as .dll?

Comment: @J. Vermeire, using any hex editor.

Comment: That's what I've tried so far, but the DLL always ends up being unreadable... Altho, I suspect the SQL Server to alter my assembly when I add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my own problem in the question below:

[Retrieve CLR DLL from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244482/retrieve-clr-dll-from-sql-server)